# Is there a way to access enter and update selections together?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

This seems to be a regular pattern for me when using d3.js:

```
function getAttr(d,i) { ... }

things = container.selectAll("selector").data(data);
things.attr("attr", getAttr);
things.enter().append("selector").attr("attr", getAttr);
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in recent versions of D3, the `.enter()` selection merges into the update selection after you've processed it. That is, instead of

```
things = container.selectAll("selector").data(data);
things.attr("attr", getAttr);
things.enter().append("selector").attr("attr", getAttr);
```

you can write

```
things = container.selectAll("selector").data(data);
things.enter().append("selector");
things.attr("attr", getAttr);
```

Not that much shorter, but it saves you quite a bit of code if you're setting a large number of different attributes, handlers, etc.